# Array = List<Array> .get(int): Program crashes

Tags: java, android, crash

Why is this code crashes the program?

```
NormalListII = Enemy.NormalLootsListII.get(PostionToDelete);
```

There is more code:

```
public class One
{
    int PostionToGet = 0;
    Loots[] NormalListII = new Loots[] { };
    public void switch() 
    { 
        (...)
        Enemy enemy;
        NormalListII = Enemy.MyLoots1.get(PostionToGet);
    }
}

public class Enemy
{
    public static ArrayList<Loots[]> MyLoots1 = new ArrayList<Loots[]>();
    public static ArrayList<Loots[]> MyLoots2 = new ArrayList<Loots[]>();
    public static ArrayList<Loots[]> MyLoots3 = new ArrayList<Loots[]>();
    public static ArrayList<Loots[]> MyLoots4 = new ArrayList<Loots[]>();
    //Loots is a class.  

    public Loots[] ToList1 = new Loots[] {new Loots(1, "7"), (...) };
    public Loots[] ToList2 = new Loots[] {new Loots(2, "48"), (...) };
    public Loots[] ToList3 = new Loots[] {new Loots(3, "29"), (...) };
    public Loots[] ToList4 = new Loots[] {new Loots(4, "16"), (...) };

public Enemy() 
{
    MyLoots1.add(ToList1);
    MyLoots2.add(ToList2);
    MyLoots3.add(ToList3);
    MyLoots4.add(ToList4);   
}
```

I don't know why this crashes the program.

I am leeching the program in the debbuger and at this line

```
(NormalListII = Enemy.NormalLootsListII.get(PostionToDelete);)
```

program is crashing.

Comment: Add error messages / stacktrace.

Comment: If you are not creating any `Enemy` instance, all the `MyLoots#` lists remain empty.

Comment: Then show the full code

Comment: Oh sorry! I defined only "Enemy enemy;" I add "Enemy enemy = new Enemy" and it works :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call constructor of Enemy class as you have added item to array list there and here you are accessing element at 0 position but actually arraylist don't have any item so it results in crashing